# Debian 11 freezes with Firefox

Tags: debian, firefox, freeze, ram

I am new to Linux currently studying Computer Engineering and we were told we needed to install a Linux distro in our machines, I decided to install Debian 11.

I've been able to resolve most problems I faced so far, but this one I do not know how to solve it, it seems that from time to time Firefox beginns consuming a lot of memory and eventually computer freezes and I'm forced to hard reset it. I know that's the problem because I force-end Mozilla Firefox from system monitor, and it goes down an stunning 5 GB or so everytime I do it.

I used to have Windows 10 in the past and Firefox also consumed a lot of memory but computer didn't freeze.

My computer is an HP 15-dw0043dx.
My FFox Version is 78.13.0esr (64-bit)

Add-ons: Password Manager, uBlock Origin, VideoDownloadHelper

I had to hard-reset FFox again and it had around 35 tabs opened, pages are usually, gmail, google classroom, udemy, khan academy, cs50.ide, facebook, twitter, whatsapp web, youtube, discord, etc... I do a heavy use for academic purposes.

[image: This is what usually happens after hard-termination when I'm able to do it]

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: May I ask... if you're new to Linux, why did you choose Debian 12? Debian 11 is the current stable version, released Aug 14 -21; less than a month ago. The upcoming release is for a good reason labeled "unstable" - see https://www.debian.org/releases/. I'd suggest getting rid of that one and installing Debian 11 instead, unless you want to spend a lot of time fighting against eventual bugs that will take months to fix. The only ones that can help you with problems at this stage are really Debian developers.

Comment: Sorry! My bad! Yeah I have 11 xD

Comment: Haha :-D This is indeed a bit odd. My FFox (on Deb10) has currently 16 tabs open, and the RAM consumption is stable, maybe 2.5GB. I've not bumped into this even once yet... let's hope I won't when I upgrade. What's your FFox version? How many tabs do you have open (approx) when this happens? That sounds to me like the issue might be caused by a "heavy" site, or one of your plugins. Do you frequent "heavy" sites? Have you tried disabling your plugins? Please dont't answer in comments, update the question with more info. The devil's in the details; the more the better :-)

Comment: I would disable VideoDownloader and most definitely keep Facebook closed. I'd also suggest removing the rest of the SoMe pages from the picture. Check out https://rambox.app/#home - I've used it for about a year for email, Twitter, Whatsapp (Web), Discord, Facebook Messenger... basically all my messaging. Might be an idea to do the same for the time being. I've not noticed Youtube, Udemy, Khan and the like doing anything funky, but I'd keep an eye on them nonetheless. Or any sites that have video or other interactive content. I guess that'd include Google Classroom - no experience here :-)

Comment: Your system is running very low on RAM. As to where it's gone consult with `top`

Comment: Try to find the cause with about:performance in FF

Comment: [I'm having a similar problem with Firefox misbehaving](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740272/firefox-freezes-cant-be-killed-and-debian-11-xfce-cant-be-shut-down), but unlike you, there is plenty of RAM available, so it's not exactly the same problem. Maybe the solution to my problem can help you solve yours.